# How to allow numbers from 20 - 50 in a text-field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have text field where only numbers are allowed. But i've one more requirement in this. I want to validate the field when user enters numbers below 20 and above 50. May i know if there is any way to achieve this. Below is simple code for the same.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="marksdif" class="form-control" id="marksdif" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" placeholder="Enter Marks to be Compared" autocomplete="off" >
```

**jQuery**

```
function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the number with if condition below 20 and above 50 .

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
function check(){
  var input = parseInt($('#marksdif').val());
  
if(input){
  if(input < 20 || input > 50)
     {
  $('#result').html('not Allow range between 20-50')
          }
else{
    $('#result').html('Allow')
         }
  }
else{
  $('#result').html("")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="marksdif" class="form-control" id="marksdif" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" oninput="check()" placeholder="Enter Marks to be Compared" autocomplete="off" >
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Ok that was good. thank you. But is it possible to show the errror while entering the value in input and also show the validation error below the input

Comment: ya its possible. you need Validate at the time of input?

Comment: Always Welcome...! @Jeeva